# Can we interchange JSON schema with YAML schema? or viceversa?

Tags: json, yaml, swagger, schema

I have a device application which gets the data in JSON format. This JSON format is generated by another web based application using a YAML schema.

Now, as the web tool validates this JSON data file against the YAML schema, my device application also has to validate it against a schema. Since, the resource on my device is limited and we already have json schema validation in place, we are restricted to use schema in JSON format only.

So, my question is could we replace the YAML schema with JSON schema for the web tool? The web application has Swagger.

On another note, is there any existing script or open source tool to convert YAML schema to JSON schema?

Not sure about the OpenAPI definition. Its a simple schema file that will be used to validate JSON data. The JSON schema (draft v4) has below format. Our device application is in C++ language. Not sure about what is used in Web Tool, but it has some Swagger framework that generates the JSON data file for us.

```
{
  "$schema": "https://json-schema.org/draft/2019-09/schema",
  "definitions": {
  ...
  
    "foobar_Result" : {
      "type" : "object",
      "properties" : {
        "request" : {
                "type" : "integer"
              },
        "success" : {
                "type" : "boolean"
              },
        "payload" : {
                "type" : "array", "items" : {"$ref" : "#/definitions/foobar_Parameter"}
              }
      },
      "required" : ["request"],
      "additionalProperties" : false
    }
  },
  "$ref" : "#/definitions/foobar_Result"
}
```

Comment: What is the language you are using?

Comment: By "YAML schema" and "JSON schema" do you mean "an OpenAPI definition in YAML/JSON format"?

Comment: @SupunWijerathne: The device app is using C++. Not sure about web end.

Comment: @Helen: The JSON schema sample format is embedded above. Its a very simple schema format and uses JSON version draft v4. It may not be OpenAPI specification compatible.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking converting between API specification formats then this tool might help https://www.apimatic.io/transformer/